# Using Tor network for Java sockets

Tags: vidalia, java

Is it possible to use Tor network for Java application usage? For example, can I program socket program in Java to use Tor network to hide application data package exchange?

Comment: Actually all you need is SOCKS5+DNS wrapper, not a special components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SilverTunnel-NG](https://sourceforge.net/p/silvertunnel-ng/) is able to provide access to the Tor Network on a Socket level.

You can checkout the [Sample code here](https://sourceforge.net/p/silvertunnel-ng/wiki/Sample%20Code%20%3A%20Check%20if%20Tor%20Connection%20works/)

The easiest way is to use maven and include the following dependency into your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.silvertunnel-ng</groupId>
  <artifactId>netlib</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Probably don't use the project. It doesn't appear to use entry guards or many other sane protections.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to have TOR on my Java applications.

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", TOR_IP);
System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", TOR_PORT);
```

The `TOR_IP` and `TOR_PORT` should be `"127.0.0.1"` and `"9150"` by default if you didn't mess with TOR.

I also managed to find some really old code on how to communicate with TOR to ask for a new identity through Java and created a class for it.

[TorControl.java](http://pastebin.com/M5ris0Dz) (You should change the constant COOKIE_FILE since I hard coded it)

[TorReader.java](http://pastebin.com/JPUqv8S5)

It is used like this.

```
TorControl tc=null;
try {
    tc = new TorControl();
    tc.authenticate();
    tc.useProxy();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Couldn't connect to the TOR control port "+CONTROLPORT);
}
```

And then when you want to change your identity simply do `tc.newIdentity()`

Note: `tc.useProxy()` will already run the first snippet I posted to make Java run with TOR.

Comment: You can use [`PROTOCOLINFO`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt#n1217) to discover the path of a cookie file, if one is present, rather than hardcoding the path.

Comment: Also, are you aware if java handles socks5 properly, IE that it doesn't do the DNS lookups locally? Also there is already https://github.com/guardianproject/jtorctl for using Tor's control port which you might find more useful, and currently maintained.

Comment: I don't remember if this is the one I found, but I remember that I tried to use one but it wouldn't compile, so I just rewrote the part that interested me (new identity). And about the DNS I don't really know. I never looked it up because I only used TOR to get new IPs.